# Subprocess.run and an unknown amount of files, how?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

So I am currently trying to make something that uses mkvmerge to merge audio, video and an unknown amount of subtitle files. For now, those subtitle filepaths are in a list.

Here is my issue. I cannot for the life of me think of a way of putting this into subprocess run, without throwing an error. If I combine the subtitle names into a single string, mkvmerge throws an error, so each file would need to be inside "","" themselves.

So, the command without subtitles looks like this:
`subprocess.run(['C:\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe', '-o', f'E:\Videos\{output_filename}.mkv', 'E:\Videos\viddec.mp4', 'E:\Videos\auddec.mp4'])`
So this will produce a working video.

AFAIK, a properly formatted subprocess call including two subtitles would need to look like this.
`subprocess.run(['C:\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe', '-o', f'E:\Videos\{output_filename}.mkv', 'E:\Videos\viddec.mp4', 'E:\Videos\auddec.mp4', 'E:\Videos\eng.srt', 'E:\Videos\nor.srt'])`

Is it possible to add variables like that, as individual strings into a subprocess.run call, so that it will function properly? or is there perhaps a different method/call I cannot think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the list of arguments *before* the `subprocess.run` call, as long as you need it to be, and pass that list in the call.

Comment: Yea, another point where I feel absolutely moronic. I had tried that before, but I realize now I must have put it into [] inside the run() method, and not as a simple variable. I'll accept the answer as soon as I can. Thank you.